# How to move database for a website from one computer to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, iis-7

I need some help with moving the database files (.mdf, .ldf) for a website (hosted on IIS) from one computer to another computer. The website is running under IIS under one computer and there is another computer that has Sql Server database for this website. Basically I want to disconnect the database connection for this website from old computer and want to link it up with the new computer where I want to move the database files. How do I go about making these changes? Are there any things that I should be concerned about? Please advise.

Comment: In this case if you no longer need database on 1 server. Just detach it, move files to another server and attach it.

Answer (score 0):

**Option one**: Detach database, copy mdf (and optionaly ldf) to new location and do "Attach" at new server. You can do that from SSMS or using T-SQL:

```
EXEC sp_detach_db 'yourdatabase', 'true'

CREATE DATABASE yourdatabase
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\yourlocation\data.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\yourlocation\logdata.ldf') 
    FOR ATTACH;
```

You can even attach database back to old server, if you need that.

**Option tvo:**
Do "backup - restore".

IMHO, first option is easier.